# Encoded HTML in optionsText binding of knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to create a dropdown list with html encoded options in knockout js using options binding.

How can i decode the text returned from the function binded to the optionsText binding.

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: function(item){ return "decoded text"}"></select>
```

In general, I need a function that take a encoded html string and returns the decoded text.

i.e. the function takes something like

> `blah blah balh <sup>TM</sup>`

and return

> blah blah blah ™

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be possible. An [`option` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html) is not permitted to have other tags as content, only "[Normal character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#normal-character-data)". This does mean you can use entities, e.g. `&#8482;` or `&trade;` (which renders as "™"), which should work for your specific example.

For completeness sake, for the Knockout part, if you *were* to try what you're after, you have two options:

- utilize the `foreach` binding and create your own `option` elements with `html` bound contents (as opposed to `text` bound contents)
- utilize the `optionsAfterRender` binding to tweak the rendered option elements (thanks to @CaseyWebb for noting this option in the comments)

Comment: You _can_ do this with the options binding using the `optionsAfterRender` binding (http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyWebb/uqmt8ora/), but as you stated, it's still invalid HTML.

Comment: @CaseyWebb Ooh, didn't know about that binding, an interesting "option" :D. I've updated my answer to include it.